# Избавиться от повторной отправки формы при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, form

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно избавиться от повторной отправки формы при обновлении страницы. То-есть когда я нажимаю "обновить" мне должна загружаться эта страница уже без всяких POST запросов. Редиректить после обработки POST запроса не вариант, так как на сайте выводятся результаты этого запроса, но если человек решил обновить страницу, то значит он насмотрелся на эти результаты и ему нужна чистая страница. У меня форма и обработчик в одном файле.
**Для особо невнимательных - нужен именно POST запрос так как данные отправляются в БД, при этом эти же данные POST выводятся на страницу чтобы их видел пользователь и они должны быть на странице до тех пор пока человек ее не обновит, а значит редирект не подходит!**
Не нужно говорить что такие вопросы сто раз задавали, условия моего вопроса отличаются от стандартных!

Comment: Изучить самые основы протокола НТТР и изначально отправлять форму методом GET

Comment: Не подходит в даном случае, данные уходят в БД поэтому нужен именно POST

Comment: Если данные уходят в БД, то значит после этого можно сделать редирект, запросить данные из БД показать их. Меня поражает иногда, как люди на пустом месте создают себе проблемы из ничего.

Comment: Ну или аякс. тогда при обновлении клиент получит свою чистую форму

Comment: Данные уходят в бд и при этом результат пост запроса выводится на страницу и он там должен быть до перезагрузки, так что и редирект не катит. Поражает как некоторые не вникают в суть вопроса...

Comment: Надо просто следовать стандартам, и таких вопросов в принципе возникать не будет